# How to filter out list when text box onchanging?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

In my c# **windows forms application**,I have a **list of Students** (`Student`). `ArrayList students = new ArrayList();`
There is a **textbox** and **listbox**.

`Student` has propery called `studentId`. So when I enter a number in textbox, application should filter out the array list (**auto complete**) and shown the **suggestions** in the **listbox**.

```
private void textBoxNameForID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // MessageBox.Show("Changed: " + " Text is: " + textBoxNameForID.Text);
      if (studentsSortedList != null) 
      {     
            foreach (Student stu in students)
            {       
                 bool contains = stu.ID.ToString().Contains(textBoxNameForID.Text);
                 if (contains) 
                 {
                      MessageBox.Show("Changed: " + " Text is: " + textBoxNameForID.Text);
                 }
            }
       }
 }
```

I have tried it and no results found for my **expectations**.Please help me out with this

Comment: try this: `bool contains = stu.ID.ToString().Contains(textBoxNameForID.Text.Trim())`

Comment: Novel, why a textbox and a listbox? Normal approach would be a combobox and this problem has been solved many many times in that approach. Oh List<Student> instead of ArrayList would be a leg up.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and watching what happens on each line? Something is probably not what you expect.

Comment: textBoxNameForID has the ID?  Have you debugged this?  What is the value of textBoxNameForID.Text?

Comment: Why are you using an ArrayList and not a List<Student> ?  You don't get type safety with an ArrayList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is StartsWith for ID
Use a HasSet. List, or Array for studentHS
Even if ID is an Integer you will need to use string

```
public IEnumerable<string> Students 
{
    get
    {
        return studentsSS
               .Where(x => x.StartsWith(studentID));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `ArrayList` to `List<Student>`, then just set the data source of your `listbox` with the filtered list:

```
private void textBoxNameForID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   listBox1.DataSource = students.Where(s => s.Id.StartsWith(textBoxNameForID.Text)).ToList();
}
```

Set the `listBox` `DisplayMember` as well with the name of a property from the `Student` class. As an example:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";
```

where `Display` can be : `public string Display { get { return Id + ":" + Name; } }`